# Difference between "[class='something']" vs '.something'

Tags: html, css, dom

What is the difference between selecting in the DOM  with these formats `'.selector'` and `'[class="selector"]'`?

I would expect the same result using either of both, but the element is not found when using the second variant. Why?

```
> document.querySelectorAll('[class="cropped-profile-image__picture"]')
NodeList []length: 0__proto__: NodeList
> document.querySelectorAll('.cropped-profile-image__picture')
NodeList(2) [div.cropped-profile-image__picture.cropped-profile-image__picture--type-cover, div.cropped-profile-image__picture.cropped-profile-image__picture--type-profile]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.selector` matches any element which has *any* class `selector`. I.e. it will match `class="selector foo"`.

`[class="selector"]` matches any element that has exactly the value `"selector"` in its `class` attribute. I.e. it will *not* match `class="selector foo"`.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning `[class*="selector"]`

Comment: @AndrewBone Probably not. `[class*="selector"]` will select elements having class `abc-selector-abc`. So that's not equivalent to the other two.

Answer (score 3):

The difference being that `.something` selects all elements that have `something` class on them - **even if they have other classes**. While `[class='something']` only selects those elements that have only one class `'something'`.

In the snippet below, you can see that `.something` applies a red border to both boxes, while the `[class='something']` selector applies a background color to only the first box.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.something {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

[class='something'] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="something"></div>

<div class="something else"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an attribute selector, you are attempting to match *exactly* the string that you pass. The class attribute would need to be `cropped-profile-image__picture`, nothing more, nothing less.

For example, the following `<div>` would match your first query selector:

```
<div class="cropped-profile-image__picture"></div>
```

But this one wouldn't:

```
<div class="cropped-profile-image__picture another-class"></div>
```

Because the class attribute doesn't *exactly* reflect what you have queried.

When you query a class using a period (`querySelectorAll('.cropped-profile-image__picture')`) you are using a DOM API that will return elements that have that class, whether they have more classes or not.

Answer (score 0):

The selector only selects exact matches, but the elements also have the class

```
cropped-profile-image__picture--type-cover
```